# Creating custom view similar to index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm creating a custom view that is a slight modification of the `index.html.erb`. I'd like to be able to create a link on my web app that directs a user to this custom view called `list.html.erb`.

Here's what I've done:

1) Copied the default scaffold index view and renamed it to `list.html.erb`
2) Modified `GalleriesController` by copying the `index` method and renaming to `list`:

```
def list
 @galleries = Gallery.all

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @galleries }
 end
end
```

3) Modified `routes.rb` file like so:

```
match "galleries/list" => "galleries#list"
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find Gallery with ID=list
Rails.root: /Users/scervera/Sites/MDN

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb:28:in `show'
```

In my search on stackoverflow I was unable to find any similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you put the `match` outside of, and after, the gallery `resources` routing.

This means the `list` is being interpreted as the `:id` of the default RESTful mapping.

Options include:

1. Just using `index` unless you truly need them both (which seems weird).
2. Adding a `list` RESTful action as described [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (see below).
3. Changing the order of your routing and/or using a constraint to avoid route overlap. IMO this is the most-fragile and least-preferable.

To add the `list` action (option 2):

```
resources :galleries do
  get 'list', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I will try option 2 because it is less fragile than changing the routing order. One additional question on this option: is it required to list all the actions for the galleries in the "resources :galleries do" block?

Comment: @SteveCervera Nope; the default routes are still there.

Comment: Nevermind. I see from the link you provided that creating a RESTful action for each of the existing actions is not necessary. Only for my customer ones. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `galleries/list` route before all other gallery routes.

Order matters. In your case, route "galleries/:id" gets matched first and causes this error.

You can get exhaustive information about Rails routing here: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Changing the order fixed it. Thanks.